# Ubuntu 12.04 completely dead screen on first boot?

Tags: 12.04, boot-failure

So when I try and load up ubuntu for the first time, (booting from the live CD) after some time the monitor just blanks off. The other system parts are still moving, but I cannot do anything at all, seeing as I have no way of seeing the screen. It goes in this order: Boot, BIOS message, Boot menu, select CD/DVD rom drive, a few commands which pass by too quickly to read, purple screen with two icons at the bottom which stays there for about 10-15 seconds, a blinking cursor, then the monitor just blanks out and I can't do anything at all. As I stated earlier everything else was running fine except the screen which rendered everything pretty much useless. Any ideas on how to get around this?

EDIT:  For those wanting specs, here they are: my model is a HP pavillion g6 notebook, intel i5 2340m dual core processor (2.4GHZ) 6 GB ram, intel hd graphics 3000. 1366x768 display resolution. I'll try and get more specs next time I have it on.

Comment: Can you post any details about what hardware you are running? This may help.

Comment: I just edited it and added the hardware specs.

Answer (score 2):

When you burnt the live CD there could have been an error in the burring process. If you still have the opportunity you should try to reburn the live CD on the lowest burn speed. I normally use a live USB just to make sure that there are no errors in the burn. Hope that this helpes.

Comment: Given the hw specs, this seems the most likely culprit.

Answer (score 0):

There are similar issues described elsewhere - often the problem seems to be related to the graphics card -

[Why does my 12.04 Alternate CD boot to a blank screen with flashing cursor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147582/why-does-my-12-04-alternate-cd-boot-to-a-blank-screen-with-flashing-cursor/147743#147743)